# How to recreate or extract weights table from Pandas EWM function

Tags: python, pandas, regression, moving-average, exponential-smoothing

I want to implement a rolling WLS regression such that more recent data points are weighted more heavily than older ones. Pandas has the very convenient EWM object for exponentially-weighted aggregations, but to my knowledge the API only supports accessing the final aggregations. I would like to extract the actual weights matrix that multiplies the original dataframe to create the EWM dataframe, which I can then use to pass weights to some WLS software. If this is impossible, if someone could help me to manually write the function for generating such a matrix it would be much appreciated (I would almost exclusively be using the `span` parameter to generate weights, if that helps).

Comment: I believe in the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/window.html#window-exponentially-weighted), you can find the function used. And the alpha from span is described in this [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html#pandas-dataframe-ewm). Is it what you look for?

Comment: @Ben.T The doc describes the theory behind the EWM weighting, but I don't want to re-implement the math from scratch if this is avoidable